# Show two tables specific column data into one list?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

I have two tables Customer and Subscription in which Customer has the list of customers and Subscription contains the Customer and Packages.
In the customer list i want to show how many packages each customer has.

Subscription Model

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name="subscriptions")
    package = models.ForeignKey(Package, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    valid_start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    valid_end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    usage_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    transaction = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

Customer Model

```
class Customer(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    mobile_number = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="user_data/profile_picture", blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Countries, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.ForeignKey(States, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(Cities, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    pincode = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    number_of_logins = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
```

Expected Result : I want to show the package field data from Subscription Model into the list of Customer model.

- name      - no.    - emaiId- pakages_subbed
- customer1 - mobile - email - package1,package2
- customer2 - mobile - email - package4,package1

Actual Result : Only Customer field data

Comment: `{{ customer.subscriptions.all|length }}` should show you that

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `annotate` in your queryset much as [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate)

I think

```
query = Customer.objects.annotate(subscription_count=Count('subscriptions'))
```

ought to do it (with the count available as `object.subscription_count` for any object retrieved from this query)

This is just one database query, returning only `Customer` objects, whereas `{{ customer.subscriptions.all|length }}` will be a lot of them (and will probably also retrieve all the Subscription objects just to count them).

If you wanted greater access to the `Subscription` and `Package` objects you could do

```
Subscription.objects.all().order_by("client__id", "package__name")...
```

(I made up `"package__name"`) which should get you the subscriptions grouped firstly by customer and then ordered by package name for each customer.

Comment: Ok i tried this it does show me subscription counts for each customer, but i want the packages name with the customer list in one query set if possible.

Comment: Subscription to Customer is many to one. You could query Subscriptions ordered by `client__id`  as per my second suggestion, and annotate the subscriptions returned  with `package__name`, but I think you'll have to deal with merging multiple subscriptions pointing at the same customer in your code. I may be wrong, I'm nothing like a DB guru. You could also annotate subscriptions with selected Customer fields to save fetching customer instances.

Comment: I have edited my question and mention how i want my list should be in expected result, do you have ideas how to achieve that particular result.

Comment: As above. You'll get a list of 4 subscriptions in order (C1 P1) (C1 P2) (C2 P1) (C2 P4). You'll have to deal with merging them into two rather than four  actions for  (C1 P1+P2) (C2 P1+P4) in code (or consult a DB guru), but you can be sure that if the next subscription  refers to a different customer, no subsequent subscription will refer to a customer already processed.  This, or just select customers, and for each customer iterate over subscriptions.